# Descobrir qual tipo de Codificação foi usado

Tags: sql-server

Ha uma forma de descobrir qual tipo de codificação foi usado para um campo de uma tabela?
Preciso dar manutençao num sistema, porem queria saber se tem como pelo sql server.

Comment: "codificação" refere-se ao tipo de dados ou ao conjunto de caracteres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso "codificação" refira-se aos tipos de dados, há várias formas.

Você pode utilizar [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql), ao informar "BaseType" no parâmetro *property*.

```
-- código #1
CREATE TABLE Super (Nome varchar(50), Idade smallint, Salário money);
INSERT into Super values ('Aparício', 18, 2000);

SELECT top (1) sql_variant_property (Nome, 'BaseType'),
       sql_variant_property (Idade, 'BaseType'),
       sql_variant_property (Salário, 'BaseType')
  from Super;
```

---

Também pode utilizar INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE Super (Nome varchar(50), Idade smallint, Salário money);

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 where TABLE_NAME = 'Super';
```

Detalhes em [System Information Schema Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql).

---

Mas a melhor forma é pelo editor visual do Management Studio (ou outra ferramenta similar).

Comment: seria abuso pedir a sintaxe deste comando no sql server? sou bem iniciante nisso

Comment: Obrigado, mas este comando me mostra so o tipo dos campos, nao mostra a codificação, se é md5, sha1